# Joomla Gantry Framework ie8 LESS/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, joomla3.4

I'm developing a Joomla!3 with Gantry Framework site.

For some reason, in IE8 starts to load well, but then it loose all the style.

The CSS file generated through LESS compiler is loaded:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/~gravymedal/templates/issencial/css-compiled/master-715683b378e45e6ccb0b443125b30f7d.css" type="text/css">
```

Can anyone test it in native IE8 and try to figure it out?

http://109.71.43.2/~gravymedal/index.php

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess a "help me debug my pages" stuff is quite offtopic here but either way: The problem is clearly in one of the js scripts included (most likely it tries to alter some styles, fails in IE and leaves the whole thing in a erroneous state). Actually if you disable scripts there you'll see it yourself (so this problem has nothing to do with the CSS actually).

Comment: The idea of debug my pages is not so right, I've only mention that because I'm using IETester and all css are loaded...

I've disabled all external js scripts but it still not load CSS properly. In my PC I can see 1 or 2 seconds the normal layout, but then it desappears...

Answer (score 0):

Well  it's not an answer.

After breaking my head for too much time, what I've done was start over.

Fresh joomla install, all components, plugins and modules and everything become fine...

Don't unsderstand why, but let's move on!

Thanks to everyone!